# Laravel put or patch validation with custom form request class fails

Tags: php, laravel-8

By creating new laravel model with api resourceful controller and from new auto-generated create and update form request classes, it always fails the validation.

With custom classes it works with post/get but for put and patch it returns validation invalid data. Without custom classes it works for any methods.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an easier/better way that I don't know about (please let me know), at the moment what I do is override `validationData()` in the `FormRequest`, and then call it from the controller:

```php
    public function validationData()
    {
        $payload = request()->json()->all(); // get payload for PUT/PATCH method
        $attrs = array_keys($this->attributes());
        return array_filter($payload, function($key) use ($attrs) {
            return in_array($key, $attrs);
        }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    }
```

and then in the controller:

```php
    $input = $request->validated();
```